# troubleshooting dates with ifelse()

Tags: r

I've got a data frame with a date variable with tens of thousands of entries. I think there may be a data entry mistake somewhere, because I can't turn it into a date class variable or process it in lubridate().

In this MWE the first observation (a1) is a legitimate date in the format I'd expect my dates to be. The other observations (a2-a7) represent different kinds of data entry mistakes. I'd like to test each observation in the date variable, to see if the observation is a legitimate date in the expected format.

I've tried to use regular patterns and ifelse(), but I can't get the code to work. I'd like to end up with something like df2 (although it doesn't have to be a data frame), so that I can easily identify the IDs of any date variable observations that may require attention. Any help would be much appreciated.

Starting point:

```
df1 <- data.frame(varID=c("a1","a2","a3","a4","a5","a6","a7"),varDate=c("01/01/2015","0101/2016","01/012017","35/01/2018","01/17/2019","01/01/20200","abc"))
```

Desired outcome:

```
df2 <- data.frame(varID=c("a2","a3","a4","a5","a6","a7"),VarIssue=c("format issue","format issue","format issue","format issue","format issue","format issue"))
```

Current code:

```
ifelse(df1$varDate == (^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$),"ok","format issue")
```

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but why not use `as.Date` using the "ok" `format`, and find the `NA` ("format issue"): `is.na(as.Date(df1$varDate, format = "%d/%m/%Y"))`

Comment: Whilst I can turn it into a factor or character, it won't let me turn it into a date class  variable.

Comment: @Henrik I like the logic, but the provided Regex will accept multiple date formats, using either `/`, `-`, or `.` as the separator.

Comment: @Henrik shouldn't something like `as.Date('01-01-20000000', '%d-%m-%Y')` fail to parse like `as.Date('2000000-01-01', '%Y-%d-%m')` does?

Comment: @rawr No, "_Each input string is processed as far as necessary for the format specified: any trailing characters are ignored._" (`?strptime`).

Comment: @Henrik I see, interesting decision

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues, you can't use Regex alone, it needs to be called within a function that accepts a Regex pattern, and you need to double escape pronoun characters.

In R you have to use the double escape like so: `\\d`, so your pattern becomes:

```
 pattern <- '^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\\d\\d$'
```

The we use `grepl` (which returns a logical vector) to check each row:

```
df1$check <-  ifelse(grepl(pattern,df1$varDate)==TRUE,"ok", "format issue")

  varID     varDate        check
1    a1  01/01/2015           ok
2    a2   0101/2016 format issue
3    a3   01/012017 format issue
4    a4  35/01/2018 format issue
5    a5  01/17/2019 format issue
6    a6 01/01/20200 format issue
7    a7         abc format issue
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the following is off-topic, but if you are having problems with date formats, consider using package `lubridate`, its `character` to `Date` conversion functions recognize a large number of formats and don't give it up at the first sign of trouble.

```
library(lubridate)

mdy(df1$varDate)
#[1] "2015-01-01" "2016-01-01" "2017-01-01" NA           "2019-01-17"
#[6] NA           NA          
#Warning message:
# 3 failed to parse.
```

As you can see only `3 failed to parse.` The others were correctly coerced to class `Date`. Then you would use a much simpler `ifelse` but the result would obviously be very different.

```
df3 <- data.frame(varID = df1$varID)
df3$VarIssue <- ifelse(is.na(mdy(df1$varDate)), "format issue", "ok")
df3
#  varID     VarIssue
#1    a1           ok
#2    a2           ok
#3    a3           ok
#4    a4 format issue
#5    a5           ok
#6    a6 format issue
#7    a7 format issue
```

Only 3 `"format issue"`.